# Loading video from internet source in windows store app C#

Tags: c#, video, load, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm trying play a video from an internet site like
http://videofun.me/embed?w=718&h=438&video=ongoing/tesagurebukatsumono03.mp4

I tried loading the page in webView control but it says it needs flash player although it is already installed

I tried loading in Media Element

```
<MediaElement HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" Margin="119,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="872" Source="http://videofun.me/embed?w=718&amp;h=438&amp;video=ongoing/tesagurebukatsumono03.mp4"/>
```

but it shows nothing

can anyone help me on this one:D?

Comment: Please check an answer or add more help to us

Answer (score 0):

I don't why it's not working using videofun.me URLs, but it should work. If you can switch to YouTube I've solution for you to play in Windows 8 app.

XAML

```
<WebView x:Name="ie" />
```

C#

```
ie.NavigateToString("<iframe width='854' height='510' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/fNtPv8W7Bf0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
```

`MediaElement` won't work the URL is not a direct link to MP4 video but it's a webpage.

Comment: it cannot be youtube I tried this method but webview doesn't show flash content I can run it in MediaElement though if I manage to extract the video stream somehow from the page... I need to show content from sites like videofun.me . if someone knows how to view these kind of sites normally in webview that will also work  for me

Comment: I am also in confusion. Why YouTube is working and not videofun.me. Both is using Flash.

Comment: I tried to find out I reached a dead end seems like it is a problem that no one has an answer to it somehow you can run only youtube with webview and also in mediaElement there is a way to do it .. but other sites like videofun just don't work for some reason